# ta-insert-video to embed video, no redirection

Tags: angularjs

In my posts’ TinyMCE frontend editor one can insert video URLs just using a button. The post outputs a thumbnail preview of the video but clicking on it one is redirected to the original source. I wish to see the video start in its frame. But this is not about changing the embed code because it’s a Angular.js class, namely ta-insert-video:

```
function j(a, b, c, d) {
    return "img" === a && b["ta-insert-video"] && ("ta-insert-video" === c || "allowfullscreen" === c || "frameborder" === c || "contenteditble" === c && "false" === d) ? !0 : !1
}
```

Is there just a little tweak to that function in order to start the video in its frame?

Comment: Hey, triaging this.. we may need a little more context. Please review and add some more information so we can help you with an answer that will be great!

Comment: I think I cannot be of much help. I have found that class in only two files:

Comment: I think I cannot be of much help. I have found that class in only two files, which I think are default Angular files:textAngular-sanitize.min and textAngular.min.js. And the code where the tag is the one above, plus a bigger one. Maybe those files can be found on Angular documentation. I don't know